# Character in negated set - exclude when not surrounded by two specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Assuming I have a following string:

```
"test | test - string-test | test - it is some string"
```

I want to remove everything after last hyphen or pipe surrounded by spaces (including both).

So i have such regex so far:

```
/ [-|] [^-|]+$/
```

and when used in `replace` method got this as expected:

```
"test | test - string-test | test"
```

But it fails when string is something like this:

```
"test | test - string-test | test - it is some-string"
```

I want `"test | test - string-test | test"`, but get `"test | test - string-test | test - it is some-string"`.

How to achieve expected result as described above with regex?

Working snippet:

```js
const string1 = "test | test - string-test | test - it is some string";
const string2 = "test | test - string-test | test - it is some-string"

const regex = / [-|] [^-|]+$/

const result1 = string1.replace(regex, '');
const result2 = string2.replace(regex, '');

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Is [**lastIndexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) going to do the job for you? -> `"test - string-test - it is some-string".substr(0, "test - string-test - it is some-string".lastIndexOf(' - '))`

Comment: I've updated the question. It may be hyphen or pipe in a string. Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Last index approach

Here is a solution which is not using regular expression. It might be suitable for your case since your logic is to find last index of a string occurrence and remove everything after that.

```js
// Option extend String.prototype
String.prototype.theLastIndexOf = function () {

  var theLastIndex = -1;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var idx = this.lastIndexOf(arguments[i]);
    if (idx > theLastIndex) {
      theLastIndex = idx;
    }
  }
  
  return theLastIndex;
}

// Option stand alone function
function _trimAfter(str, sought){
  var theLastIndex = -1;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < sought.length; i++) {
    var idx = str.lastIndexOf(sought[i]);
    if (idx > theLastIndex) {
      theLastIndex = idx;
    }
  }
  
  return theLastIndex >= 0 ? str.substr(0, theLastIndex) : str;
}

var str1 = 'test | test - string-test | test - it is some-string';
var str2 = 'test | test - string-test - test | it is some-string';
console.log('Before: ' + str1)
console.log(' After: ' + str1.substr(0, str1.theLastIndexOf(' - ', ' | ')));
console.log('Before: ' + str2)
console.log(' After: ' + _trimAfter(str2, [' - ', ' | ']));
```

### Regex approach

If you want to match everything after last occurrence of string with regex you can use this regular expression: `/\s[-|]\s(?!.*\s[-|]\s)(.*)/`, where the meanings in the context of this regex are:

- `\s[-|]\s` mean match `-` or `|`
- `(?!.*\s[-|]\s)` mean not followed by `-` or `|`
- `(.*)` mean match everything after the above two conditions

```js
var str1 = 'test | test - string-test - test | it is - some-string';
var str2 = 'test | test - string-test - test | it is some-string';

console.log('Before: ' + str1);
console.log(' After: ' + str1.replace(/\s[-|]\s(?!.*\s[-|]\s)(.*)/, ''));

console.log('Before: ' + str2);
console.log(' After: ' + str2.replace(/\s[-|]\s(?!.*\s[-|]\s)(.*)/, ''));
```

Comment: Probably the best approach, except for extending the `String` prototype. Standalone function would be less prone to accidentally breaking other code.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for detailed solutions, especially for regex one. It works as I expected. Thank you.